# If a thread calls Acquire() on a critical section, will that lock be freed if a different thread calls Release()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++builder, critical-section

I'm using Embarcadero's critical section implementation, **TCriticalSection,** but their documentation doesn't answer my question.

If we have a global critical section object:

```
namespace
{
   //delphi style class must be constructed on the heap
   TCriticalSection* criticalSection = new TCriticalSection();
}

//somewhere in thread 1...
criticalSection->Acquire();

//somewhere in thread2...
criticalSection->Release();
```

Will the release call in thread2 open up the critical section?

I ask because I have RAII class which releases the lock during destruction, so we don't enter deadlock if the code throws an exception. However the critical section is only a part of the method.

```
//...
CRITICAL_SECTION_LOCK lock( criticalSection );
OneAtATimePlease();
lock.Release(); 
//...
```

So I don't want to put the critical section inside OneAtATimePlease() because then we'll be handling locks for every single call to that method in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TCriticalSection` is a wrapper for a Win32 [Critical Section object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530.aspx), where `Acquire()` simply calls [`EnterCriticalSection()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608.aspx), and `Release()` simply calls [`LeaveCriticalSection()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684169.aspx).

The [`LeaveCriticalSection()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684169.aspx) documentation states:

> A thread uses the `EnterCriticalSection` or `TryEnterCriticalSection` function to acquire ownership of a critical section object. To release its ownership, the thread must call `LeaveCriticalSection` once for each time that it entered the critical section.
>
> **If a thread calls `LeaveCriticalSection` when it does not have ownership of the specified critical section object, an error occurs that may cause another thread using `EnterCriticalSection` to wait indefinitely.**

So, DO NOT attempt to unlock the critical section in a thread that does not currently own the lock.

It is perfectly OK (and preferred) for you to move your `lock` variable inside of `OneAtATimePlease()`, where it belongs:

```
void OneAtATimePlease()
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION_LOCK lock( criticalSection );
    ...
}
```

Think about what would happen using your original code if multiple threads call `OneAtATimePlease()` at the same time but a thread DOES NOT lock the critical section:

Thread 1

```
CRITICAL_SECTION_LOCK lock( criticalSection );
OneAtATimePlease();
lock.Release();
```

Thread 2

```
CRITICAL_SECTION_LOCK lock( criticalSection );
OneAtATimePlease();
lock.Release();
```

Thread 3

```
// NO LOCK!!!
OneAtATimePlease();
```

Thread 3 could execute `OneAtATimePlease()` **while** Thread 1 or 2 are already inside of it!  That defeats the whole purpose of using a critical section.   If you move the lock inside of `OneAtATimePlease()` then there is no way for multiple threads to get out of sync with each other (unless one of them erroneously unlocks the critical section when it does not own the lock, but your RAII wrapper would prevent that).

This would even work recursively and safely, per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530.aspx):

> When a thread owns a critical section, it can make additional calls to `EnterCriticalSection` or `TryEnterCriticalSection` without blocking its execution. This prevents a thread from deadlocking itself while waiting for a critical section that it already owns. To release its ownership, the thread must call `LeaveCriticalSection` one time for each time that it entered the critical section.

```
void OneAtATimePlease()
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION_LOCK lock( criticalSection );
    ...
    if (some condition)
        OneAtATimePlease();
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

"Critical Section" is really a MS Windows concept. It's undefined what happens if a thread fails to unlock a critical section, and it is also undefined what happens if another thread tries to unlock a critical section it didn't lock.

What you suggest (another thread unlocking a critical section) is impossible because the *locks* are thread-local, even though the critical section is shared, and therefore each thread can only unlock its own lock.

Comment: I added some logic to the RAII class to handle the event of a double release, but the Release() method of CRITICAL_SECTION_LOCK just ends up doing  criticalSection->Release().  So while the lock object is thread local, the operation is on the global TCriticalSection, thefore releasing from different threads would be undefined then?

Comment: @syco_link: It would make sense to add an `assert` in debug mode, so you can catch the offending code. And yes, when you try to unlock a critical section, you can only release a lock held by the current thread, not a random other lock on some other thread.